# String truncation error in Delphi DBExpress/Firebird paramatised queries

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, dbexpress

I have a query in Delphi using DBExpress TSQLQuery that looks like so

```
ActiveSQL.sql.add('SELECT * FROM MYTABLE where MYFIELD=(:AMYFIELD) ');

ActiveSQL.ParamByName('AMYFIELD').AsString    := 'Some random string that is to long for the field';

ActiveSQL.Open;
```

If I run it, when it executes the open command I get the following exception

> in class TDBXError with message
>   'arithmetic exception, numeric
>   overflow or string truncation'.

This is caused by the string in AMYFIELD been longer then the tables field length, MYFIELD is Varchar(10), If I trim it down to a shorter string it works OK, and if I add the string directly into the SQL like so

```
  ActiveSQL.sql.add('SELECT * FROM MYTABLE where MYFIELD="Some random string that is to long for the field" ');
```

it works OK, i.e. does not complain about the truncation, now if this was an insert/update I would want to know about the truncation , but as its just been used for a search I would like to stop it.

Is there any way I can tell DBExpress that it is OK to truncate my strings? or is there a workable work around for this

I would like to avoid having to add something like

l_input := copy(l_input,0,fieldLength-1);

as looks messy and would make maintaining the code harder.

I am using Delphi 2007 with Firebird 2 via the interbase driver if that helps?

UPDATE:

@[Erick Sasse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391348/string-truncation-error-in-delphi-dbexpress-paramatised-queries#393694) it looks like your right, I found the error message on the firebird FAQ site http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq79/

@[inzKulozik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391348/string-truncation-error-in-delphi-dbexpress-paramatised-queries#392779) the LeftStr works fine, although I cannot get ActiveSQL.ParamByName('AMYFIELD').Size to work , but this still seams messy to me, and harder to maintain.

I have also seen a method that adds substr to the SQL: something like

```
select * from mytable where myname = substr(:MYNAME,0,10)
```

Again looks harder to maintain, Ideally I would like a Firebird/ DBExpress config setting that fixes this problem, but until I can find one I'll go with inzKulozik's solution and hope the table structure does not change to much.

Comment: Maybe you should set maximum length limit in user controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l_input := copy(l_input,**0**,fieldLength-1);
```

You can't copy substring from position 0!

Try this:

```
l_input := LeftStr(l_input, fieldLength);
```

or

```
ActiveSQL.ParamByName('AMYFIELD').AsString := LeftStr('Some random string that is to long for the field', ActiveSQL.ParamByName('AMYFIELD').Size);
```

or

```
with ActiveSQL.ParamByName('AMYFIELD') do
  AsString := LeftStr('Some random string that is to long for the field', Size);
```

Comment: I didnt know about leftStr, ill give it a go monday

Answer (score 2):

This error message is from Firebird, not DBX. I think DBX sends parameters to the database exactly the way you enter it, so it should be Firebird job to truncate it.